# How to change total according to item quantity

Tags: node.js, paypal-rest-sdk

I've got a paypal payment at my site. Looks like this:

```
app.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:1234/success",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:1234/cancel"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": req.body.user_name,
                    "sku": "001",
                    "price": "25",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": req.body.persons_count
            }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "25"
            },
            "description": req.body.user_name + " with email " + req.body.email + " just ordered " + req.body.persons_count + " places"
    }]
    };

    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            res.send('on my way');
            console.log(payment);
        }
    });
})
```

If I change total field in amount object (this is what I wanna do) I get a 400 response (bad request). How can I make a payment like this:

```
"amount":{
"total": req.body.persons_count * 2
}
```

Where `req.body.persons_count` variable is a variable I get from a post request from one of the forms I have earlier.

Fighting with that code showed, that both `price` and `total` values have to be equal however I want the price of a single item be different from the total amount I wanna get. Huge thanks!

By the way quantity value has to be equal to 1. In all other cases app crahes.

Answer (score 0):

Total amount should be sum of items amount, shipping amount, tax and other fees.

In your case, total : Item price * Item quantity

sample,

```
 "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "20",
                "details": {
                    "shipping": "1.20",
                    "tax": "1.30",
                    "subtotal": "17.50"
                }
            },
            "description": "Payment description",
            "invoice_number": "1231123524",
            "custom": "custom data",
            "item_list": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Ground Coffee 40 oz",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "price": "7.50"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Granola bars",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "quantity": 5,
                        "price": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

You can also refer https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create